# How to preg_match_all to get the text inside the tags "<h3>" and "<h3> <a/> </h3>"

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, preg-match-all

Hello I am currently creating an automatic table of contents my wordpress web. My reference from
https://webdeasy.de/en/wordpress-table-of-contents-without-plugin/

**Problem :**
Everything goes well unless in the `<h3>` tag has an `<a>` tag link. It make `$names` result missing.

I see problems because of this regex section

```
preg_match_all("/<h[3,4](?:\sid=\"(.*)\")?(?:.*)?>(.*)<\/h[3,4]>/", $content, $matches);

// get text under <h3> or <h4> tag.
$names = $matches[2];
```

I have tried modifying the regex (I don't really understand this)

```
preg_match_all (/ <h [3,4] (?: \ sid = \ "(. *) \")? (?:. *)?> <a (. *)> (. *) <\ / a> <\ / h [3,4]> /", $content, $matches)

// get text under <a> tag.
$names = $matches[4];
```

The code above work for to find the text that is in the `<h3> <a> a text </a> <h3>` tag, but the h3 tag which doesn't contain the `<a>` tag is a problem.

**My Question :**
How combine code above?
My expectation is if when the first code result does not appear then it is execute the second code as a result.

Or maybe there is a better solution? Thank you.

Comment: There is a better solution, which is not to use regex to parse HTML (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). Instead, use a more appropriate tool like [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that will remove any tags inside of header tags

```
$html = <<<EOT
<h3>Here's an <a href="thing.php">alternative solution</a></h3> to using regex. <h3>It may <a name='#thing'>not</a></h3> be the most elegant solution, but it works
EOT;

preg_match_all('#<h(.*?)>(.*?)<\/h(.*?)>#si', $html, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $num=>$blah) {
   $look_for = preg_quote($matches[0][$num],"/");
   $tag = str_replace("<","",explode(">",$matches[0][$num])[0]);
   $replace_with = "<$tag>" . strip_tags($matches[2][$num]) . "</$tag>";
   $html = preg_replace("/$look_for/", $replace_with,$html,1);
}

echo "<pre>$html</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer @kinglish is the base of this solution, thank you very much. I slightly modify and simplify it according to my question article link. This code worked for me:

```
preg_match_all('#(\<h[3-4])\sid=\"(.*?)\"?\>(.*?)(<\/h[3-4]>)#si',$content, $matches);    
    $tags = $matches[0];
    $ids = $matches[2];
    $raw_names = $matches[3];
    /* Clean $rawnames from other html tags */
    $clean_names= array_map(function($v){
        return trim(strip_tags($v));
    }, $raw_names);
    $names = $clean_names;
```